# Callbacks or hooks, and reusable series of tasks, in Ansible roles

Tags: ansible

I'm struggling with making my Ansible roles somewhat composeable and re-usable.

I have a role that performs several series of steps. Depending on the other roles being applied to a host, other roles need to run tasks at each step.

I'm working with PostgreSQL and PostgreSQL extension management, but to keep it simple let's use an example of a webserver and some apps that run on it.

- role: webserver
- role: myapp
- role: myotherapp

The `webserver` role:

- installs the webserver
- templates its configuration
- sets up its database
- starts the webserver

The `myapp` role needs to be able to add some settings to the webserver's config that *must be applied before the webserver's database is created*. It must also perform some actions before the webserver is first stated.

The `myotherapp` role *also* needs to add some settings to the webserver's config before first-run, without clobbering the settings from `myapp`. It must also perform some actions after the webserver has first started, restart it, do some more work, and restart it again.

(This is contrived, but expresses all the needs of my real use case without going into way more about PostgreSQL innards that you ever wanted to know).

I thought I should be able to use handlers for this. Have `webserver` just fire `notify`s at each relevant step, so other roles could hook those notifications to append to lists or add keys to hashes used for config templating, fire their own tasks, etc. Have a `restart_webserver` handler that `myotherapp` can notify each time it wants to issue a restart, without having to know how that restart is actually performed. etc.

However:

- If there's a notification, the handler *must* exist. Ansible doesn't permit optional handlers.
- If there's more than one handler for a notification, Ansible just picks the first one and ignores all the rest.
- Notifications fire only at the end of a play section. You can't fire them immediately. There's `meta: flush_handlers` but it flushes *all* handlers, even those from other unrelated roles and tasks that might not be expecting their handlers to run early.
- It's astonishingly difficult to *append* to a list, or *add keys* to a dictionary. So it's quite hard to compose multiple related roles, without just manually gluing the configuration together with some `host_vars` yml.

So handlers and notifications don't seem to be how to do this.

How does one write composeable tasks and roles?

Am I trying to use a bicycle wheel as a hammer? Are you just not meant to use roles this way? It seems consistent with the concept of a *role*.

Should anything vaguely re-usable or less than totally linear be written by dropping Ansible's tasks/roles/vars/etc system and doing it in Python as an Ansible module? If so, is there any practical way to implement most of the brains of such a module as Ansible task-lists, variables yml files, etc, and just having the control logic in the module, so the module doesn't have to re-implement tons of stuff?

---

The "PostgreSQL guts" version:

- A `postgres_server` role. Installs Pg from distro packages or from source code as required. Has lots of vars in `defaults/main.yml` that can be overridden to control behaviour. Provides the facility to template a PostgreSQL configuration to supply parameters for `postgresql.conf`. Lets the caller override or prepend lines to `pg_hba.conf`. initdb's PostgreSQL once installed. Starts PostgreSQL once configured. Knows how to start, stop and restart the `postgres_server` (handler). Exposes facts to tell other roles where PostgreSQL is installed.
- A `bdr_extension` role. Assigned to a host where the [bdr](http://bdr-project.org/docs/stable/) extension will be installed in PostgreSQL.  Needs to see facts exposed by `postgres_sever` to find out how to install. Can fetch/compile/install BDR from git or install from OS packages.

  PostgreSQL *cannot start succesfully* if `bdr` is in the configuration's `shared_preload_libraries`. So `postgres_server`'s starting of the server must be delayed until this is installed, if this extension is enabled.
- A `bdr_node` role. Depends on `postgres_server` and `bdr_extension`. Knows the PostgreSQL configuration options required to allow BDR to run on PostgreSQL, e.g. `max_wal_senders = 20`. Needs to be able to ensure that the PostgreSQL config option `shared_preload_libraries` has `bdr` in its comma-separated list of values when `postgres_server` generates the config. Overrides the default `pg_hba.conf` template in `postgres_server` to enable replication entries.

  This role must run some SQL commands *after* PostgreSQL has started.
- A `pg_stat_statements` role. Can install `pg_stat_statements` extension from git or OS packages. Needs to see facts exposed by `postgres_sever` to find out how to install. Needs to be able to append some extension-specific lines to `postgresql.conf`. Needs to be able to append `'pg_stat_statements'` to the `shared_preload_libraries` setting in the PostgreSQL server configuration.

  PostgreSQL *cannot start succesfully* if `shared_preload_libraries` is in the configuration's `pg_stat_statements`. So `postgres_server`'s starting of the server must be delayed until this is installed, if this extension is enabled.

So a BDR node is-a PostgreSQL server, and has-a BDR extension and pg_stat_statements extension, as well as others.

I *expected* to be able to expose handlers in the `postgres_server` role, and invoke them from other roles as needed to invoke appropriate activities in the `postgres_server` role, like a DB server restart, but it doesn't seem to be designed that way at all.

Am I getting it all completely backwards by thinking of Ansible roles as actually modelling *roles*?

Comment: Can we make the example a little more concrete? A `webserver` is a role that sets up what? `apache` + a `postgresql` database + a `django`/`php`/whatever application? This may need to be broken into two or more roles (in fact I think I use five roles for such a thing).

Comment: @AntonisChristofides Concrete target added. I don't understand why you'd break something up into more roles; is that to work around the inability to reorder actions around roles?

Comment: No. I have `apache` and `apache-vhost`. `apache` installs `apache` and performs some essential configuration; `apache-vhost` installs an apache vhost. Likewise, I have `gunicorn` and `gunicorn-instance`. So, for a django application, I have `apache`, `apache-vhost`, `gunicorn`, `gunicorn-instance`, `postgresql`, and the role for the django application. For some django applications, I also have `myapp` and `myapp-instance`. Possibly irrelevant to your problem, but since you asked...

Comment: OK, so different situation. The issue here is as if, when you add an "apache-vhost", it has to increment the (imaginary) "apache" "max-vhosts" setting by one and add its name to the apache config's "vhosts_lists" in the apache config template. And you might have different numbers of vhosts with different names on different hosts. Plus you have to make sure to start Apache only after all vhosts are installed. That's roughly comparable to the problem.

Comment: @CraigRinger Did you find a solution here? I'm looking for the exact same thing.

Comment: @thorink Only limited and clunky. The handler improvements in 2.0 helped, and the latest revision has some inheritance improvements too. But mostly you just have to endure incredible tedium, lots of cross-role includes, and ridiculous numbers of tiny "roles" that are not roles at all. It makes the role system half-useless.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL so I'm unsure of the contents of the various configuration files you mentioned, but if you need to allow multiple roles to contribute to a single configuration file, I've accomplished this in one of two ways depending on what the configuration file supports:

1. Use a configuration file with lots of include statements to include additional configuration files located in sub-directories. This works well with something like Apache for rewrite rules, application-specific configuration directives, and virtual hosts.
2. Assemble the configuration file from multiple partial configuration files stored in a directory using the [assemble module](http://docs.ansible.com/assemble_module.html). I've used this method to construct a master.cf file for Postfix as I had a `postfix` role and another role that needed to add to the Postfix master.cf file. So I modified the `postfix` role to create a /etc/postfix/master.d directory and a handler that assembles the files in that directory into a master.cf file. Unfortunately, as you pointed out, since I can't call the handler in the `postfix` role from another role, I had to duplicate that handler in my additional role. It's slightly less than idea but it works and it's idempotent.

Comment: Neither will really work in cases where you have to append to a variable in the configuration, e.g. "increase max_connections by two when this role is applied" or "add this extension to the extension_list setting when this role is applied". I don't think pgsql-hackers will take kindly to my proposing that we implement `+=` in the configuration file syntax "because Ansible can't cope with appending to variables" ;-)