# Appending to lists or adding keys to dictionaries in Ansible

Tags: ansible

(Related to [Callbacks or hooks, and reusable series of tasks, in Ansible roles](https://serverfault.com/q/685670/102814)):

Is there any better way to append to a list or add a key to a dictionary in Ansible than (ab)using a jina2 template expression?

I know you can do something like:

```
- name: this is a hack
  shell: echo "{% originalvar.append('x') %}New value of originalvar is {{originalvar}}"
```

but is there really no sort of meta task or helper to do this?

It feels fragile, seems to be undocumented, and relies on lots of assumptions about how variables work in Ansible.

My use case is multiple roles (database server extensions) that each need to supply some configuration to a base role (the database server). It's not as simple as appending a line to the db server config file; each change applies to the *same line*, e.g. the extensions `bdr` and `pg_stat_statements` must both appear on a target line:

```
shared_preload_libaries = 'bdr, pg_stat_statements'
```

Is the Ansible way to do this to just process the config file multiple times (once per extension) with a regexp that extracts the current value, parses it, and then rewrites it? If so, how do you make that idempotent across multiple runs?

What if the config is harder than this to parse and it's not as simple as appending another comma-separated value? Think XML config files.

Comment: Y'know what? I like the cut of your side-effect-ful jib ☺

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can merge two lists in a variable with `+`.
Say you have a `group_vars` file with this content:

```
---
# group_vars/all
pgsql_extensions:
  - ext1
  - ext2
  - ext3
```

And it's used in a template `pgsql.conf.j2` like:

```
# {{ ansible_managed }}
pgsql_extensions={% for item in pgsql_extensions %}{{ item }}, {% endfor %}
```

You can then append extensions to the testing database servers like this:

```
---
# group_vars/testing_db
append_exts:
  - ext4
  - ext5
pgsql_extensions: "{{ pgsql_extensions + append_exts }}"
```

When the role is run in any of the testing servers, the aditional extensions will be added.

I'm not sure this works for dictionaries as well, and also be careful with spaces and leaving a dangling comma at the end of the line.

Comment: You can, but you have to do it all in `group_vars`, the roles can't take care of the details of setting up the extensions themselves. It's appending vars from *roles* that I'm particularly looking for, so one role can append to a var exposed by another role.

Comment: Does your base role know about each extension role? I've had a similar case where I was able to leave the concatenation up to a `with_items` sentence.

Comment: no, and that is really the issue. In one deployment the base role might be al

Comment: No, and that is really the issue. The base role might be used standalone in one deployment, with one extension in another deployment, and with two different extensions in another. Rather than having to copy and edit the role for each, with the resulting maintenance nightmare, I want to just make it reusable enough that I can bring it in as a git submodule.

Comment: It seems like if you try to do this to concatenate two lists, it thinks it's an infinitely recursive template because the left hand side is also on the right hand side. Am I misunderstanding how to use this?

Comment: @Ibrahim> despite looking declarative, ansible roles actually are imperative. So the line will be run exactly once, concatenating current value of `pgsql_extensions` with `append_exts` and overwriting `pgsql_extensions` with the result.

Comment: @spectras At least as of Ansible 2.7 this does NOT work. As Ibrahim suggested, this causes an error: "recursive loop detected in template string".

Answer (score 49):

Since Ansible v2.x you can do these:

```yaml
# use case I: appending to LIST variable:
- name: my appender
  set_fact:
    my_list_var: '{{my_list_myvar + new_items_list}}'

# use case II: appending to LIST variable one by one:
- name: my appender
  set_fact:
    my_list_var: '{{my_list_var + [item]}}'
  with_items: '{{my_new_items|list}}'

# use case III: appending more keys DICT variable in a "batch":
- name: my appender
  set_fact:
    my_dict_var: '{{my_dict_var|combine(my_new_keys_in_a_dict)}}'

# use case IV: appending keys DICT variable one by one from tuples
- name: setup list of tuples (for 2.4.x and up
  set_fact:
    lot: >
      [('key1', 'value1',), ('key2', 'value2',), ..., ('keyN', 'valueN',)],
- name: my appender
  set_fact:
    my_dict_var: '{{my_dict_var|combine({item[0]: item[1]})}}'
  with_items: '{{lot}}'

# use case V: appending keys DICT variable one by one from list of dicts (thanks to @ssc)
- name: add new key / value pairs to dict
  set_fact:
    my_dict_var: "{{ my_dict_var | combine({item.key: item.value}) }}"
  with_items:
  - { key: 'key01', value: 'value 01' }
  - { key: 'key02', value: 'value 03' }
  - { key: 'key03', value: 'value 04' }
```

all the above is documented in:  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries

Comment: use case IV just appends `u'(': u\"'\"}"`

Comment: thanks, @ssc. I noticed it's not working with ansible `2.4.x` (FIXED)

Comment: according to usecase #4, I have added the default value to handle the **undefined error** in my scenario: `set_fact: my_dict_var: '{{my_dict_var|default({})|combine({item[0]: item[1]})}}'`.
 The undefined error comes when some filtering is used or no results is registered.

Comment: Mr S.K. Venkat, the sample code here only demonstrates very specific thing (adding of dictionary items from tuples).
If you need to do something else, this code is not your copy-paste.

Answer (score 3):

you need to split the loop into 2

```
--- 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks: 
    - include_vars: stacks
    - set_facts: roles={{stacks.Roles | split(' ')}}
    - include: addhost.yml
      with_items: "{{roles}}"
```

and addhost.yml

```
- set_facts: groupname={{item}}
- set_facts: ips={{stacks[item]|split(' ')}}
- local_action: add_host hostname={{item}} groupname={{groupname}}
  with_items: {{ips}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost all answers here require changes in tasks, but I needed to dynamically merge dictionaries in vars definition, not during run.

E.g. I want to define some shared vars in `all` `group_vars` and then I want to extend them in some other `group` or `host_vars`.
Very useful when working for roles.

If you try to use the `combine` or `union` filters overwriting the original variable in var files, you will end in infinite loop during templating, so I created this workaround (it's not solution).

You can define multiple variables based on some name pattern and then automatically load them in role.

`group_vars/all.yml`

```
dictionary_of_bla:
  - name: blabla
    value1 : blabla
    value2 : blabla
```

`group_vars/group1.yml`

```
dictionary_of_bla_group1:
  - name: blabla2
    value1 : blabla2
    value2 : blabla2
```

role code snippet

```
tasks:
  - name: Run for all dictionary_of_bla.* variations
    include_tasks: do_some_stuff.yml
    with_items: "{{ lookup('varnames','dictionary_of_bla.*').split(',') }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: _dictionary_of_bla
```

`do_some_stuff.yml`

```
- name: do magic
  magic:
    trick_name: item.name
    trick_value1: item.value1
    trick_value2: item.value2
  with_items: "{{ vars[_dictionary_of_bla] }}"
```

It's just a snippet, but you should get the idea how it works.
note: lookup('varnames','') is available since ansible 2.8

I guess it would be also possible to merge all variables `dictionary_of_bla.*` into one dictionary during runtime using the same lookup.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to set exact lists of variable names, but only the pattern and user can set it dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the nice trick !
Is there a similar way in Ansible 2.7 ?

Comment: I wish I could give you a million upvotes. Thank you for sharing this workaround!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure *when* they added this, but at least for dictionaries/hashes (NOT lists/arrays), you can set the variable [hash_behaviour](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour), like so: `hash_behaviour = merge` in your `ansible.cfg`.

Took me quite a few hours to accidentally stumble upon this setting :S

Comment: this is very handy, but beware to enable it e2e on existing codebase. may break some eggs.

Answer (score -5):

`Ansible` is an automation system, and, concerning configuration file management, it's not very different from `apt`. The reason more and more software offers the feature to read configuration snippets from a `conf.d` directory is to enable such automation systems to have different packages/roles add configuration to the software. I believe that it is not the philosophy of `Ansible` to do what you have in mind, but instead to use the `conf.d` trick. If the software being configured does not offer this functionality, you may be in trouble.

Since you mention XML configuration files, I take the opportunity to do some whining. There's a reason for the Unix tradition of using plain text configuration files. Binary configuration files do not lend themselves well to system automation, so any kind of binary format will give you trouble and will likely require you to create a program to handle the configuration. (If anyone thinks XML is a plain text format, they should go have their brains examined.)

Now, on your specific `PostgreSQL` problem. `PostgreSQL` does support the `conf.d` trick. First, I would check whether `shared_preload_libraries` can be specified multiple times. I did not find any hint in the documentation that it can, but I would still try it. If it cannot be specified multiple times, I would explain my problem to the `PostgreSQL` guys in case they have ideas; this is a `PostgreSQL` issue and not an `Ansible` issue. If there is no solution and I really couldn't merge the different roles into one, I'd implement a system to compile the configuration on the managed host. In this case, I'd probably create a script `/usr/local/sbin/update_postgresql_config` which would compile `/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf.jinja` into `/etc/postgresql/9.x/main/postgresql.conf`. The script would read the shared preload libraries from `/etc/postgresql/shared_preload_libraries.txt`, one library per line, and provide them to jinja.

It is not uncommon for automation systems to do this. An example is the Debian `exim4` package.

Comment: PostgreSQL supports a `conf.d` include mechanism and thankfully uses plaintext files. However, there are some configuration options where multiple extensions may have opinions about it - e.g "increase max_wal_senders by 10 from whatever it was before".

Comment: It seems like you're saying that the application should be changed to work around limitations in the configuration management system, or I should give up on having re-usable roles.