# How to do an array or hash merge in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

An [ansible-sensu-plugin-install](https://github.com/030/ansible-sensu-plugin-install) role has been created in order to install sensu-plugins using [this code](https://github.com/030/ansible-sensu-plugin-install/blob/master/tasks/main.yml#L12):

```
- name: be sure sensu-plugins-{{ item.name }} is installed
  command: sensu-install -p {{ item.name }}:{{ item.version }}
  when: "'sensu-plugins-{{ item.name }} ({{ item.version }})' not in installed_plugins.stdout"
  with_items: "{{ sensu_plugin_install }}"
```

There a two other roles that require sensu-plugins. [The first role](https://github.com/030/ansible-sensu-server) requires [the mailer plugin](https://github.com/030/ansible-sensu-server/blob/master/defaults/main.yml#L18):

```
sensu_plugin_install:
  - name: mailer
    version: 1.0.0
```

and [the second one](https://github.com/030/ansible-sensu-client) requires [multiple plugins](https://github.com/030/ansible-sensu-client/blob/master/defaults/main.yml#L17):

```
sensu_plugin_install:
  - name: cpu-checks
    version: 1.0.0
  - name: disk-checks
    version: 2.0.1
  - name: http
    version: 1.0.0
  - name: memory-checks
    version: 1.0.2
  - name: ntp
    version: 1.0.0
```

Role one and two have been included in one playbook.

**Current outcome**

Either the `mailer` defined in role one or the plugins defined in role two will be installed. Commenting out one of the `sensu_plugin_install` declarations will install plugins related to role one or two, e.g. only the mailer plugin will be installed:

```
TASK [030.sensu-plugin-install : be sure sensu-plugins-{{ item.name }} is
    installed] ***
    changed: [host.example.com] => (item={u'version': u'1.0.0', u'name':
    u'mailer'}) => {"changed": true,
```

if the `sensu_plugin_install` of the second role has been commented out.

**Expected outcome**

The expected outcome is that all plugins will be installed, i.e. six in this case instead of one, i.e. `mailer` or five.

**Discussion**

It looks like that the arrays will not be merged as either one or five plugins will be installed instead of six and one of the two needs to be commented out in order to force the installation of a plugin.

One option to solve this issue is to merge these arrays, i.e. `sensu_plugin_install + sensu_plugin_install`. For example, in Puppet it is possible to merge arrays using [`hiera_array`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/function.html#hierahash). How could this be done in Ansible?

Using [Two different variables](https://serverfault.com/questions/685673/appending-to-lists-or-adding-keys-to-dictionaries-in-ansible) in order to solve the issue is not an option as the functionality of one role is used and it is not preferred to add another variable to this role if another role would like to install sensu plugins.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/685673/126632

Comment: @MichaelHampton I would like to see that it is possible to do a kind of `sensu_plugin_install + sensu_plugin_install` instead of having two different variables.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that. And it's probably not very clean to try.

Comment: @MichaelHampton In puppet one could do merge array and merge hash.

Comment: @techraf I have edited the question

Comment: @030 Unfortunately, it's even less clear now. I can't see why the task can't run twice: once for one `sensu_plugin_install` value (five plugins), the other time for another (one plugin). It's not a handler that gets executed once.

Comment: @techraf all three roles are included in the same playbook

Comment: I don't understand what you say. There is no term "to include a role" in Ansible vocabulary.

Comment: @techraf [This](https://github.com/030/ansible-sensu-server/blob/master/meta/main.yml#L18) is not including roles?

Comment: @030 No! You set/declared role as a dependency for another role. That's a far cry from **including** in a **playbook**.

Comment: Based on what do you conclude that it is a `far cry`? Are there any open related bugs for example and how would you solve this issue?

Comment: I already explained why the words you used were misleading. As for the problem itself, it is also not the one you are asking about. More than a question of combining two hashes, it is a problem of simultaneous access to variables with the same name defined in different roles as default values. Ansible wasn't designed to deal with such cases, it has strict variable precedence, and you probably won't get it solved unless you fork and rewrite the engine; or use hardcoded values for your roles; or move the variable assignment to a higher level, for example to the playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I had to define two different variables rather than using the same one, e.g. `sensu_plugin_install`. After giving the second dict a different name like `sensu_plugin_install_other`, the two arrays were able to merge:

```
 with_items: "{{ sensu_plugin_install }} + {{ sensu_plugin_install_other }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this role from ansible galaxy https://galaxy.ansible.com/eugene0707/merge_custom_vars/

I did it some time ago for same reason. It can deep merge dictionaries from several vars files and set custom precedence of merging.

This role can work under Ansible 2.0+